# Error tokenizing data with Pandas from a tsv file

Tags: python, pandas

I have got dataset named `train.tsv.7z` and `test.tsv.7z`. I unzip them in my Mac with unarchiver (double click) so I have the `train.tsv` and `test.tsv` now.

Then I am reading those files with pandas using

```
PATH='data/projData/'
tables = pd.read_table(PATH)
```

But I am getting error

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Calling read(nbytes) on source failed. Try engine='python'.
```

Looking into other stackoverflow thread, it seems the error is due to the file being corrupted. But not sure how to solve this issue.

I am using python3.6 conda environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work this way.

You have to specify a single file (not a directory):

```
train = pd.read_csv('data/projData/train.tsv', sep='\t')
```